# how to choose right predictors for multivariable linear regression?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, multivariate-analysis, linear-model, prediction

I am new to statistics, And I am trying to work on this [dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Automobile) , The format , Attribute information is given thereon dataset page.

Suppose I am trying to predict highway-mpg or peak-rpm, Then if my dependent variable is highway-mpg now how to choose other independent variables, because currently there are 17 independent variables (if we exclude string attributes), Then how i am going to choose right independent variables from those 17 attributes, should I go with all ? 
but that is the right way or not because I don't think all the variable are affecting highway-mpg attribute.

Please correct me if i am going wrong, I tried to find ways and there are two ways which i thought my own :

if we find sum of rediuals of each attribute and subtract it to the sum of residuals of the dependent variable (highway-mpg) then which values have less distance dependent variable those can be used.

Example : from another dataset where i was predicting mpg :

These are the distance from dependent variable(mpg) of residuals from other independent variables :

```
22681.302142857145   #cylin
-4257774.7201785715  #dispo
-555474.6391836754   #horsepo
-282076702.22846943  #weight
20842.962959183675   #accelator
18513.156734693872   #year
23565.289387755103   #origin
```

Second way i thought if i subtract the sum of dependent variables with each independent variables then fewer distance variables can be used.

As I said I am new into this field so please give me more details how I will choose right predictors and what are other ways?

Answer (score -1):

The proper way for choosing the predictors (when having a bunch of them) **isn't** picking them one-by one (unless you're using some forward selection algorithm, which clearly isn't the case).

Denote your dependent variable (e.g mpg) as $y$ and the rest of the variables as a matrix $X$ (its columns are cyl, disp, hp etc.). Assuming linear relation is equivalent to posing $y=X\beta$ and we try to find $\beta$. The Least Squares solution is $\hat{\beta}^{OLS}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$.

Assuming normal model (go with me on this as other options require advanced understanding), which is $y_i\sim~N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$, we get that the covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates is $Cov(\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$, thus the variance of $\hat{\beta}_j$ is $\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}$. We define the statistic $t_j$ to be $t_j=\frac{\hat{\beta}_j}{\sqrt{\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}$ (coefficient estimate divided by its stdev). Using the proper t-distribution cumulative function we obtain the p-value for the hyothesis $H_0:\beta_j=0$. You get all of these using `summary` function on your `lm` object.

Now, with these p-value in hand, you can get sense of which variables you can try and drop from the model. Keep in mind that while some variables might seem insignificant as individuals, they could be significant as a bunch. This (examining the significance of a bunch of variables) is done by F-test, which compares two models.

**Example**: I once had a dataset of Lakers games data, with scoring rate as the dependent variable and some 15 predictors, including variables indicating the presence of some players on court (e.g $x_9$=1 if Kobe's playing, 0 if he's on bench` $x_{10}$=1 if Pao Gasol playing, 0 otherwise and so on). Looking at the players' vars separately, they all seemed insignificant. Looking at them as a bunch showed that I shouldn't drop them as together they explain a lot of the variance.

To sum up, you shouldn't be picking your variables one-by-one but rather use the well-known methods and interpret their results.

Comment: so should i include and work with all predictors ?

Comment: yes. start with everything and then consider dropping variables.

Comment: Only, if you do as Spätzle suggests, the coefficients, *p*-values, *F* statistics, etc. in your final model will carry an invisible and unreported "conditional on decisions I made about these variables that do not appear in this reported model." **You should include *all* theorized variables in your model.** *Reporting* is another story (e.g., tabling only results you wish to highlight, with, say, a full table in the appendix).